# Java attain >50% compression ratio

Tags: java, compression, deflate

I am trying to compress the pdf files(sometimes images). I need a compressor in java which will help me compress my files. I need the size to be less than half the size of the original document. I tried deflator given in java apis. But it was not very successful. Please help me on this.

Comment: There are hard limits on how much a given bunch of data can be compressed. The compressed size may not be smaller than the information content of the data, and that's the ideal result - real world results will be worse than that. It's entirely possible that the PDF files are already as compressed as they reasonably can be. (The PDF supports compression internally.)

Answer (score 5):

You need to compress the images individually more than they are already (which can reduce quality)  Trying to compress images with a general lossless compression program won't be very successful as the data is compressed already.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure you would have already explored open source solution but `LZMA` is one of the best in compressing the files to a greater extent. Try the `Java library` for `7zip` in the below link. 
http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html

Comment: Using LZMA would maybe help if the documents were mostly textual and not compressed already. As impressive as the algorithm is, I doubt it can recompress data with any significant space savings.